# Firebase app crashes when uploading profile image

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-authentication, heap-corruption

[image]

When uploading the profile image to firebase the app crashes getting this error "malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x280165460
*** Incorrect guard value: 10751132320
"app-name"(945,0x16f5df000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I pasted the code from my entire Controller with exception to the gradient function seeing as that is not necessary.

The purpose of this controller is simply to upload an image to Firebase. IMPORTANT: This crash doesn't happen all the time but when it does it is fatal to user experience. Furthermore, this crash does not happen on my setting page which gives the user an option to add three more images to their profile. Not once has that feature crashed on me.

Please I desperately need help!

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import UserNotifications
    import SDWebImage

      extension EnterPhotoController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,        UINavigationControllerDelegate {

      @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage

        let imageButton = (picker as?        CustomImagePickerController)?.imageBttn

        imageButton?.setImage(selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

    self.imageFull = true

    dismiss(animated: true)
    saveImageToFirebase(profImage: selectedImage ?? UIImage(named: "CrushtLogoLiam")!)

    }
}

class EnterPhotoController: UIViewController {

    var imageFull = Bool()

    var name = String()
    var birthday = String()
    var age = Int()
    var bio = String()
    var school = String()

    let selectPhotoButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)

        //button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "top_left_profile"), for: .normal)
        //button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        //button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .heavy)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CrushtLogoLiam"), for: .normal)

        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        //button.imageView?.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSelectPhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 70
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = "Select Your Profile Picture"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .heavy)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


        return label
    }()

    let errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.text = "Please select a photo"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .heavy)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        return label
    }()


    let doneButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 27.5, weight: .heavy)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.6749386191, blue: 0.7228371501, alpha: 1)
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true

        button.layer.cornerRadius = 22

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDone), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()


    lazy var selectPhotoButtonWidthAnchor = selectPhotoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 275)
    lazy var selectPhotoButtonHeightAnchor = selectPhotoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 275)

    @objc func handleSelectPhoto() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Access your photos", message: "Can Crusht open your photos so you can select a profile picture?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default){(UIAlertAction) in
//            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
//            imagePickerController.delegate = self
//            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
            let imagePicker = CustomImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.imageBttn = self.selectPhotoButton
           self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupGradientLayer()

        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [selectPhotoButton, doneButton])
        view.addSubview(stack)

        stack.axis = .vertical

        view.addSubview(label)

        label.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: view.bounds.height/9, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30))

        stack.anchor(top: label.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 4, left: 30, bottom: view.bounds.height/5, right: 30))

        stack.spacing = 15

        view.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.isHidden = true
        errorLabel.anchor(top: stack.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20))
    }


    @objc fileprivate func handleDone(completion: @escaping (Error?) ->()) {
        if imageFull == false {
          errorLabel.isHidden = false
            return
        }
        else {
            handleRegister()
        }
    }


    var phone: String!
    var gender = String()
    var sexYouLike = String()

    let animationView = AnimationView()

    fileprivate func handleRegister() {

        print("whatever")


    }



    fileprivate func saveImageToFirebase(profImage: UIImage) {

        view.addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.fillSuperview()

        let filename = UUID().uuidString
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/images/\(filename)")
       guard let imageData = profImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else {return}
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (nil, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print(err)
                return
            }
            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in

                if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                    return
                }

                let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString ?? ""

                self.saveInfoToFirestore(imageUrl: imageUrl)
            })
        }
    }

    fileprivate func saveInfoToFirestore(imageUrl: String){
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
        let docData: [String: Any] =
            [
                "ImageUrl1": imageUrl,
                ]
        //let userAge = ["Age": age]
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData(docData, merge: true) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
                return
            }
            let customtabController = CustomTabBarController()

            self.animationView.removeFromSuperview()

            self.present(customtabController, animated: true)

        }
    }


I simply want the app to save the image and move on to the home tab controller
```

Comment: Can you add the entire stack trace of the crash to your question?

Comment: I added an image to help clarify. I'll try to reproduce the crash now. Also I watched your talk on Geohashing and it was very interesting!

Comment: Apologies: trying to recreate the crash but it isn't happening....which I guess is a good thing. I changed the code to be more simple and am not passing many values between functions